# SAPUI5 setTimeout() --> Object has no method

Tags: javascript, settimeout, sapui5

I have the following coding:

```
var myFunc = function(){
 myMessagesDialog.close();
 app.back();
}
window.setTimeout(myFunc, 10000);
```

I have a SAPUI5 application and have a normal busydialog. What I want to achieve is that when you press on a button the above coding should be executed. In my browser it runs without any complications ... but when I start the app on my mobile device I get the following error:

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 10 : 
Uncaugt TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'cancelTimeout'
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'cancelTimeout'
```

Does anybody know what I make wrong here?

Greetings
Stef

Comment: I think you're looking for `clearTimeout`.  Remember, you pass a number into it. `var to = setTimeout(...); clearTimeout(to);`

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function demo() {
                that.refreshDashboard();
            }, 2500);
refreshDashboard : function () {
    //function code here
}
```

Comment: you can use `this` to call your function. `var that= this` isnt needed.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the error is created not because of setTimeout(). It was created by the control which I used. I don't now exactly why but somehow the sap.m.BusyDialog() caused this error... I'm using now the sap.m.Dialog() and it works.

Greetings